# Terminar laço quando um entrada for vazia

Tags: python, loop, while, null

Tenho a seguinte situação:
Um laço de repetição que pede nome, e 2 notas, onde a entrada de dados deve
terminar quando for lido um nome vazio, porém da maneira abaixo na segunda vez que o programa roda o nome não é pedido, alguma dica de como fazer ?

```
nome = input("Nome: ")

while nome != "":
    n1 = int(input("N1: "))
    n2 = int(input("N2: "))
```

Comment: O `nome` não está a ser lido dentro do `while` logo nunca irá terminar assim como nunca irá ser pedido de novo

Comment: Deixando o "nome" dentro do while tenho o seguinte problema:
NameError: name 'nome' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Para que o laço possa terminar com o `nome` vazio é necessário que o `nome` volte a ser lido dentro do `while`, assim:

```
nome = input("Nome: ")

while nome != "":
    n1 = int(input("N1: "))
    n2 = int(input("N2: "))
    nome = input("Nome: ") #leitura novamente aqui
```

Note que não poderia ficar apenas assim:

```
while nome != "": #dá erro nesta linha porque o nome ainda não existe aqui, só dentro do while
    n1 = int(input("N1: "))
    n2 = int(input("N2: "))
    nome = input("Nome: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tentei fazer a leitura logo no While, mas me parece que em Python isso não funciona como em Java.

Logo, uma solução, criei uma função que lê um nome e retorna o nome, enquanto esse nome for diferente de vazio, ele vai continuar dando loop.

```
nome=""
def ler():      #função para ler
    global nome
    nome = input("Digite o nome:")
    return nome #retorno da função
while ler()!="":         #comparação.
    n1 = int(input("N1: "))
    n2 = int(input("N2: "))
```